# Wraps single symbol in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have application and there is text displayed in TextView. Text is displayed like quote `"text text text."`, and if text is long. Sometimes only quote sign gets wrapped to the next line like this

```
"text text text.
"
```

It is posible to make to don't wrap single symbol?
Or for example wrap only whole words with symbols.

in this case

```
"text text text.
"
```

show

```
"text text
text."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it out, but how about this?

[`ReplacementTransformationMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ReplacementTransformationMethod.html).

You can create your own transformation on the `TextView` using [`setTransformationMethod()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29)